# Is it possible to run Appium tests on Browserstack?

Tags: appium, browserstack

I am trying Sauce Labs to run Appium tests and I want to compare it with Browserstack. The problem is that I cannot find any doc about 'running appium tests' on Browserstack.

Is it possible to run Appium tests on Browserstack?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, BrowserStack provides Appium for Selenium browser testing on iOS. For example, to run a Selenium test on iPhone 6 on BrowserStack, you need to point it to BrowserStack's Selenium hub 'http://hub.browserstack.com/wd/hub' and set the capabilities as given below :

```
'browserName' : 'iPhone'
'platform' : 'MAC'
'device' : 'iPhone 6'
```

Comment: Sorry. I forgot to mention in my question that I want to run tests for a native app (using Appium). BrowserStack only supports Selenium browser testing, but doesn't support running native apps on its emulators. Thank you @Umang

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried with setting up desire capabilities as mentioned in below link:

https://www.browserstack.com/automate/java#configure-capabilities

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is totally possible. You can create a trial account and you will get 100 minutes for app automation.And free account supports few devices too.

https://app-automate.browserstack.com/

You can select app automate.